# wysihtml5 - how disable underline tag

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I have a small problem with wysihtml5 on my site. I want to allow only a few html tags and if I remove underline from parser rules and even underline command from wysihtml5 library, I can still press CTRL(command)+U to make selected text underlined. What should I do to get rid of this behaviour?
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: thats a bug, tell them https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues (if we are talking about this editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer:** Here is my updated solution. I [updated the existing keydown event handler](https://github.com/eyecatchup/wysihtml5/commit/433053830e778e0878a1a4791c685aa04da7f9f7) (and [added a keyup handler](https://github.com/eyecatchup/wysihtml5/commit/0e8fde32ac204b14a682fbc5bcba1739e584b022) for tracking ctrl pressed state) as follows:

```
// --------- Shortcut logic ---------
var ctrlDown = 0;

dom.observe(element, "keydown", function(event) {
  var keyCode  = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode,
    command    = shortcuts[keyCode];
  if (1 == event.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('Ctrl key pressed. Setting ctrlDown = 1.');
    ctrlDown = 1;
  }
  if (85 == keyCode && 1 == ctrlDown) {
    console.log('Pressed "U" (keyCode 85), but Ctrl key still down. Don\'t fire!');
    return event.preventDefault(), !1;
  }
  if (1 == ctrlDown && !event.altKey && command) {
    console.log('Shortcut Ctrl + keyCode ' + keyCode + ' triggered.');
    that.commands.exec(command), event.preventDefault();
  }
});

dom.observe(element, "keyup", function(event) {
  // note: "event.ctrlKey" doesn't work with keyup, use keyCode/which 
  if (17 == (event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode)) {
    console.log('Ctrl key released. Setting ctrlDown = 0.');
    ctrlDown = 0;
  }
});
```

I sent you [a pull request at github](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/pull/377).

---

**Original answer:** All I needed to do, to disable the Ctrl+u keyboard shortcut, was to remove the keyCode for "u" (85) from the shortcuts object at line 8494 in `wysihtml5-0.4.0pre.js`.

Change

```
  shortcuts = {
    "66": "bold",     // B
    "73": "italic",   // I
    "85": "underline" // U
  };
```

to

```
  shortcuts = {
    "66": "bold",     // B
    "73": "italic"    // I
  };
```

and you will no longer be able to use the Ctrl+u shortcut within the editor.

Alternatively, you could catch the keydown events and disable the Ctrl+u shortcut (ie. prevent default behaviour). Something like:

```
// --------- disable ctrl+u shortcut for underlining texts ---------
dom.observe(element, "keydown", function(event) {
  if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && 'u' == String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
    // do something
  }       
});
```

Comment: I tried to remove the 85 shortcut and it didn't work, so that was the reason why I created the issue (+ it ignores parser rules).
Yeah, catching the keydown could be the solution, I was thinking about something similar, so I edited your code a bit and now I'm happy. Well, thank you a lot and 100 of my reputation goes to you :-)

Comment: Dump question.. When you removed the 85 shortcut, did you just reloaded the editor page, or have you tried a forced reload to avoid JS browser caching? To me, it happened the same. The removal of the 85 shortcut was my 1st try. When it didn't worked in the first instance, I tried the key listener and only later realized that the script was cached (though I reloaded the page a few times). Anyway, glad you found a working solution. Grüße von der Schanze ;)

Comment: I always remove the cache and test it a few times in different browsers, so removing the shortcut really doesn't work for me.
Yeah, I'm also glad it works!
Once again, Danke für Ihre Hilfe!

Comment: Odd. Tested again in latest Chrome (stable & carnary), FF, Aurora and Safari. And in all cases removing the 85 shortcut works as expected?!

Comment: wysihtml5 0.3.0 tested again in all major browsers and removing the 85 is not enough.

Comment: Odd, again. Weird caching on my side!? Sorry. Anyway, I think I found the best solution now. Tested in all major browsers with 0.3 and 0.4pre on Win and Ubuntu. I sent a pull request at github. cheers